# MySQL Python - Create a database from .sql template file

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I need to generate a lot of temporary databases through API. I have a template on how each database should look:

**Template.sql**

```
...
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `P0XXXX` ;
USE `P0XXXX` ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `P0XXXX`.`Customer_Requirement`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `P0XXXX`.`Customer_Requirement` (
  `ID` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `ModulePath` TEXT NULL,
  `AbsoluteNumber` TEXT NULL,
  `ObjectURL` TEXT NULL,
  `lk_contentType` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `lk_responsible` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `lk_requirementStatus` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `LK_CommentInt` TEXT NULL,
  `LK_CommentExt` TEXT NULL,
  `lk_Function` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `lk_Release` TEXT NULL,
  `lk_VerificationStatus` TEXT NULL,
  `lk_realisationStatus` TEXT NULL,
  `lk_FunctionalSafety` TEXT NULL,
  ...
```

I have not included the whole file, but I hope you get the idea. So using this idea, I am wondering if it is possible to replace "P0XXXX" with a custom project name (e.g. P00000). I would create this through Python:

```
def generate_temp_database(self, project_id):
    """
    Generates a new database from the standard template 
    """

    cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(TEMPLATE.sql) # However, I need to replace the default value of PXXXXX
                                 # I tried .format("P00000") and using params, but won't work in this case
    cursor.close()
    ...
```

Is there a way to dynamically replace each "PXXXXX" value with the id of the project passed as a parameter in the function (so it will create different databases with the same structure, but with a different name). I also have `.mwb' files (model files), but I am not sure how to interact with them or if they are suitable for the solution of this problem. Thank you.